# Key dump_from_b64 not found in object/dict

Tags: jaseci

[image]

[image]

When I do actions list it's there but for some reason it saying object not found and this is happening on the live server. file.dump_from_b64 works locally if I created a walker init and using it to test. The issue doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you shouldn't use the variable name `file` alongside referencing the `file` Jaseci action set.

Try

```
for f in files:
...
```

instead of

```
for file in files:
```

Comment: works great, thank you so much, rookie mistake.